# Android Eclipse AsyncTask - but result is empty - can someone have a look

Tags: android, eclipse, android-asynctask

sorry to be a pain, but I've been on this one too long and I am sure it's a easy one but I am tired and can't see it. All works fine but the 'String result' is empty

```
package com.example.me;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnLoginButton;
    TextView tmpError, tmpUsername, tmpPassword;
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters;
    String response;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tmpError = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblMessage);
        tmpUsername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);  
        tmpPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);  

        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        btnLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin); 
        btnLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg) {
                try{
                    triggerClick();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {         
                    tmpError.setText("[]" + e.toString());  
                }
            } 
        });
    }

    private void triggerClick() {  

        postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", tmpUsername.getText().toString()));  
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", tmpPassword.getText().toString()));  

        final class HttpTask
                extends
                AsyncTask<String/* Param */, Boolean /* Progress */, String /* Result */> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                publishProgress(true);
                try {
                response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://some.url/thatiknoworks/check.php", postParameters);
                            return response;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }    

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                publishProgress(false);

                result = result.replaceAll("\\s+","");  

                if(result.equals("1")) { 
                    tmpError.setText("Correct");
                }
                else {  
                    tmpError.setText("Sorry!!("+result+")");
                }
            }

        }       

        new HttpTask().execute();
    }  
}
```

come back time and time again with an empty "result" string :-(

Comment: yes changin it to "return CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://some.url/thatiknoworks/check.php", postParameters);" did it

Comment: Ok then Great.But you can Use the way I have suggested in my answer As the response of the Server will be in the form of String and can save that String globally and use else where.

Comment: ok I have edited my code above

Comment: You should not edit the Question to make it an Answer dude..This Edit in your Question makes it Error less and it would not be helpful for the peoples having same problem like you as their is no error persisting now. :)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because in the `doInBackground()` you return empty string, you should do:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            publishProgress(true);
            try {
                 return CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://some.url/thatiknoworks/check.php", postParameters);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "";
            }    

        }
```

Comment: I see what you mean, but I don't think that's it I forgot to mention that the http://some.url/thatiknoworks/check.php returns either a "1" (true) or a "0" (false) and it's this value that I want the asyncTask to give me.. so I don't really want to return anything in doInBackground() I want onPostExecute(String result) to have the httpsrequest result in it

Comment: ok if I return CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://some.url/thatiknoworks/check.php", postParameters);
it seems to be working fine :D but

Comment: ya that's it, you should return the response of the CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost() method

Answer (score 1):

The string result is empty because you're returning an empty string from `doInBackground()`.

```
return "";
```

Answer (score 1):

Please Declare `String response;` as a global variable.

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
 {
   publishProgress(true);
   try 
   {
   response=CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://some.url/thatiknoworks/check.php", postParameters);
   return response;
   } 
   catch (Exception e) 
   {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }    
 }
```